# Using SqlServer CE without installation

Tags: c++, com

Given:

- A clean machine, no SQL Server CE present.
- A set of *.sdf files (Sql Server CE databases), never mind how they got there
- The DLLs of the relevant Sql Server CE (sqlceca35.dll, sqlcecompact35.dll, sqlceer35EN.dll, sqlceme35.dll, sqlceoledb35.dll, sqlceqp35.dll, sqlcese35.dll)

Question:

- How to make available the Sql Server CE OLEDB provider implemented by the aforementioned DLLs. I am looking for a programmatic way to do so when running as a limited account.

In other words, assuming we are talking about Sql Server CE 3.5, how to make the following code succeed:

```
IDBInitializePtr spDBInitialize;
HRESULT hr = spDBInitialize.CreateInstance(CLSID_SQLSERVERCE35, NULL);
```

Note, that the machine is clean and the code is running as a limited account.

**EDIT**

There is another catch. The code is C++, I cannot use Ado.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spDBInitialize.CreateInstance()` does the following:

1. Looks up your CLSID in the Windows Registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID
2. Determines DLL from InProcServer
3. Calls `LoadLibrary()` on the DLL
4. Calls `GetProcAddress` for "DllGetClassObject"
5. Calls `DllGetClassObject` to get an `IClassFactory`
6. Uses returned `IClassFactory` to handle your `CreateInstance(NULL, IID_IDBInitialize, (void**) &spIDBInitialize)` request

In your scenario, you do cannot get pass the first step because your DLL isn't registered in the Windows Registry.

However, because you know where the SQL Server CE DLLs are you can get around this by making your code just implement 3, 4, 5 and 6.

Here's a C++ console application that opens a SDF using CoCreateInstance replacement:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <oleauto.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Include\sqlce_oledb.h"
#include "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Include\sqlce_err.h"

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Creates a COM object using an HMODULE instead of the Windows Registry
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

HRESULT DllCoCreateInstance(HMODULE hModule, REFCLSID rclsid, LPUNKNOWN pUnkOuter, REFIID riid, LPVOID FAR* ppv)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    if (hModule == NULL)
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    BOOL (WINAPI*DllGetClassObject)(REFCLSID, REFIID, LPVOID) = NULL;
    (FARPROC&) DllGetClassObject = GetProcAddress(hModule, "DllGetClassObject");
    if (DllGetClassObject == NULL)
    {
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }

    CComPtr<IClassFactory> spIClassFactory;
    hr = DllGetClassObject(rclsid, IID_IClassFactory, &spIClassFactory);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }

    return spIClassFactory->CreateInstance(pUnkOuter, riid, ppv);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Open a close a SDF file
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    // Need a loaded library so we can CoCreateInstance without the Windows Registry.
    HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\\v3.5\\sqlceoledb35.dll");

    // Open a SQL Server CE 3.5 database without using Windows Registry.
    CComPtr<IDBInitialize> spIDBInitialize;
    //hr = spIDBInitialize.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SQLSERVERCE_3_5);
    hr = DllCoCreateInstance(hModule, CLSID_SQLSERVERCE_3_5, NULL, IID_IDBInitialize, (void**) &spIDBInitialize);
    CComPtr<IDBProperties> spIDBProperties;
    hr = spIDBInitialize->QueryInterface(IID_IDBProperties, (void**) &spIDBProperties);
    CComVariant varDataSource(OLESTR("InsertYourSampleDatabase.SDF"));
    DBPROP prop = { DBPROP_INIT_DATASOURCE, DBPROPOPTIONS_REQUIRED, 0, DB_NULLID, varDataSource };
    DBPROPSET propSet = {&prop, 1, DBPROPSET_DBINIT};
    hr = spIDBProperties->SetProperties(1, &propSet);
    spIDBProperties = NULL;
    hr = spIDBInitialize->Initialize();

    // @@TODO: Do your regular OLEDB code with the opened database.
    //...

    // Close COM objects
    spIDBInitialize = NULL;

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Some things that's missing from the code snippet:

- Call `FreeLibrary()` when you're completely finished with the library (usually prior to program termination)
- Handle bad HRESULT hr return codes
- Handle LoadLibrary() failures

To get meaningful error messages for SQL Server CE operations you should consult Microsoft MSDN article [Using OLE DB Error Objects (SQL Server Compact Edition)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174513(v=sql.90).aspx). I usually start with a condense version of it here:

```
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    CComPtr<IErrorInfo> spIErrorInfo;
    GetErrorInfo(0, &spIErrorInfo);
    if (spIErrorInfo != NULL)
    {
        CComBSTR bstrError;
        spIErrorInfo->GetDescription(&bstrError);
        // @@TODO: Do stuff with bstrError
        wprintf("%s\r\n", (BSTR) bstrError);
    }
}
```

It's easier and safer to just deploy the entire SQL Server CE 3.5 folder, but, if you want a minimal set, I believe the following files are the important ones for your scenario:

- sqlceoledb35.dll - SQLCE OLEDB Provider
- sqlceqp35.dll - SQLCE Query Processor
- sqlcese35.dll - SQLCE Storage Engine
- sqlceer35EN.dll - SQLCE Native Error Strings and Resources
- sqlcecompact35.dll - SQLCE Database Repair tool

For reference, the files I believe you don't need are:

- sqlceca35.dll - SQLCE Client Agent (for Merge Replication to SQL Server)
- sqlceme35.dll - SQLCE Managed Extensions
- System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll - Managed Assembly

Comment: +1 - I am going to check it right now. I just hope their OLEDB provider does not do another `CreateInstance` inside.

Comment: It will be ok. I've used this technique successfully for sdf files in the past.

Comment: This is unbelievable! It means that SQL Server CE is the smallest embedded database! sqlceoledb40.dll is only 167K, whereas sqlite3.lib over 2M. Where is the catch?

Comment: I had to unmark, since I am running into problems. The approach has worked fine until I have renamed **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition** to **C:\Program Files (x86)\___Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition**, effectively disabling the COM base. Now `spIDBInitialize->Initialize()` fails with `E_FAIL` - not very descriptive. Any ideas as to the troubleshooting?

Comment: I am wondering what did you do to make this approach work on **a clean machine**, because `IDBInitialize::Initialize()` seems to use the `CreateInstance` API to create other parts of the implementation, which goes through the normal COM. The manual loading of the DLL only works for the root component, so how come it works for you?

Comment: I ran the code on a fresh Windows 7 machine that does not have SQL Server 3.5 installed at all. I just copied the DLLs to an arbitrary folder and did a LoadLibrary on it. In my case, I place the DLLs with my app so I used relative paths for LoadLibrary rather than the default installation path. Please debug HMODULE and HRESULT return codes. If you get FAILED(hr) then look at the HRESULT as well as GetErrorInfo() followed by spIErrorInfo->GetDescription().

Comment: LoadLibrary is OK. The problem is invoking the `IDBInitialize::Initialize()` method.

Comment: `LoadLibrary` is OK. The problem is invoking the `IDBInitialize::Initialize()` method. Note, that `IDBProperties::SetProperties` worked fine. BTW, I do extract the error message with `::GetErrorInfo`, but when I call `GetDescription` it returns `NULL`.

Comment: Error messages are meant to be provided by sqlceer35EN.dll. But, perhaps the way we're doing things prevent them from working properly. I did some experimenting and deliberately mispelt the SDF file and I did get the E_FAIL on Initialize() symptom. In my case, I knew the fix was to correct the filename. In your case, you'll have to troubleshoot further on why Initialize() isn't working. It could be anything I'm afraid.

Comment: The same code on the same input works fine when sqlce is registered. You can see in Procmon that it attempts to look in the registry for the various components. What do you see in your procmon log?

Comment: I installed Procmon. I can see it doing some reads of the registry, but not for any COM components. It never accesses the CLSID tree for anything. I can see it figuring out the load the other sqlce DLLs when it needs to that I place in the same folder.

Comment: Stupid me, I have tried to play it smartass and haven't deployed all the DLLs. It is working now, just like you said. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm really glad that it is working for you now. I think it was a good comment about deploying DLLs so I've added it to the answer.

Comment: According to [Engine Object Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173456(v=sql.100).aspx) - it appears that CompactDatabase, CreateDatabase, Repair, UpgradeDatabase, Verify and VerifyEx are in the same spot - but I'm just guessing about the connection between the DLL and the API at this point.