# DllGetClassObject return "No such interface supported" while CoCreateInstance can find it successful

Tags: c++, dll, com, sql-server-ce, sqlcedatareader

I want to use the library "sqlceoledb35.dll" to process .sdf db file without register. I know this dll is a COM dll and used in ADO.
But I can't get the target interface, it returns error "No such interface supported". 
Here is the code:

```
    CoInitialize(nullptr); 
    HMODULE hmod = CoLoadLibrary((L"sqlceoledb35.dll"), true);
    DllGetClassObject_t pDllGetClassObject =(DllGetClassObject_t)GetProcAddress(hmod,        "DllGetClassObject");
    HRESULT hr=NOERROR;
    IDBInitialize *pIDBInitialize1=NULL;
    IDBInitialize *pIDBInitialize2=NULL;
    hr = pDllGetClassObject(CLSID_SQLSERVERCE_3_5, __uuidof(IUnknown), (void**)&pIDBInitialize1);
    hr = pDllGetClassObject(CLSID_SQLSERVERCE_3_5, IID_IDBInitialize, (void**)&pIDBInitialize2);
```

But in this code snippet, `_uuidof(IUnknow)`can return a interface success, but `IID_IDBInitialize` will fail(this IID can work in `CoCreateInstance`, you will see later.

This is another code which can work correctly in the same machine with the same interface IID:

```
    CoInitialize(nullptr); 
    hr = CoCreateInstance(  CLSID_SQLSERVERCE_3_5, 
                        0, 
                        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                        IID_IDBInitialize, 
                        (void**)&pIDBInitialize);
```

So anyone can help, So that the 1st code snippet can work?
So did the method `CoCreateInstance` do more work which is a key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CoCreateInstance` (for in-proc servers) works in two stages. First, it loads the DLL and calls `DllGetClassObject` with the `CLSID` you pass, asking for `IClassFactory` interface. Second, it calls `IClassFactory::CreateInstance` on the pointer thus obtained, with the `IID` you pass.

The object that `DllGetClassObject` knows how to create - the class factory - does **not** normally itself implement any interfaces other than `IClassFactory` and, of course, `IUnknown`.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102471/using-sqlserver-ce-without-installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102471/using-sqlserver-ce-without-installation) This link is useful also