# Connect to Database through C++

Tags: c++, sql-server, database

Can someone recommend the best and cleanest way to connect to a SQL Server Compact Database through C++ and execute queries etc on it?

Cheers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776369/how-can-i-query-a-ms-sql-compact-server-3-5-database-in-c-not-using-the-ole-db

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention which database you want to log into.  I have used [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/) in the past and it worked well.